# magento 2 varien_file_csv

Tags: magento2, csv, convert, varien-io-file

I have a script from Magento 1 that I ned to convert to Magento 2. The script uses `Varien_File_Csv` that I can't find in Magento 2, and so can't the Magento 2. Where is this file in Magento 2 found? Or, if it doesn't exist, what would be its substitute in Magento 2?

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent of `Varien_File_Csv` in Magento 2 is `Magento\Framework\File\Csv`.
You can find it in `lib/internal` folders or in `vendor/magento/framework` depending on how you installed the application.

And you can use it like this.

```
$csvReader = new \Magento\Framework\File\Csv(new \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File());
```

then you can simply use it like

```
$data = $csvReader->getData('path/to/file');
```

Comment: Ok, can you also tell me how to get it using object manager or similar way?

Comment: Magento 2 first-time-installer here :)

Comment: See my edit. you don't need object manager to load it.